# Unable to solve rotating motion of object in Movie Clip Editor

Tags: tracking, motion-capture, movie-clip-editor

I have been trying to **solve** the **rotating motion** of an object (see image. i.e. a lipstick) in the Blender Movie Clip Editor. I 3D printed a lipstick-Ersatz with tracking points to facilitate the tracking. I have eleven tracks which are partly interrupted, but there should be enough overlap. The solve error is very high. I was wondering how I could make this work. I shot the footage on a tripod at 50p in 4k. In Blender I used a png image sequence for tracking.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]